# Help with proving the following inequality

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have to prove that $0\leq \sin(x)-(x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!-x^7/7!)\leq x^9/9!$, $x>0$

With the help of Taylor's theorem I got the following inequality,

$-x^9/9!\leq \sin(x)-(x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!-x^7/7!)\leq x^9/9!$. How should I proceed further? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Applying Taylor's theorem to the function $f(x)=\ sinx$ in $[0,x]$ with remainder after nine terms, I got,

$sinx=x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!-x^7/7!+\sin(\theta x)x^9/9!$

Now,$-1 \leq \sin(\theta x)x^9/9! \leq 1$

Putting the value of $\sin(\theta x)x^9/9!$ I got the previous inequality.

Comment: Did you really use the Taylor series? How? – Better use Taylor's theorem with the remainder. – Btw, the desired inequality is surely wrong for negative $x$.

Comment: Hi Martin R!! Sorry I meant to mention Taylor's  theorem! I edited the question. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Please show how you used Taylor's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower bound is obtained by applying Taylor's theorem with the remainder after *seven* terms. The seventh derivative of $\sin(x)$ is $-\cos(x)$. Therefore, if $ x > 0$ then we have with some $\theta \in (0, 1)$,
$$
 \sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + \frac{x^7}{7!}(-\cos(\theta x))
\ge x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!}
$$
since $\cos(\theta x)) \le 1$.

For the upper bound it should be
$$
 \sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \frac{x^9}{9!}(\cos(\theta' x))
\le x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!}+ \frac{x^9}{9!}
$$

Comment: Ok but how do I show it to be zero?

Comment: I got it! Thanks!!